# zcat won't unzip files properly

Tags: unix, command-line, archive, unzip, zcat

I need to unzip a compressed file on the fly in my program.  It works when I try it on my own linux computer, but for some reason the school computers fail whenever I tell them to do it.  To unzip I'm using the following command:

```
 zcat /file/address/file.tar.gz
```

and get the error:

```
 /file/address/file.tar.gz.Z: No such file or directory
```

I tried looking through the documentation but couldn't find a flag to turn off this odd behavior.

Comment: I wouldn't try to unzip the passwd file if I were you :-)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Your school's system still has the old "compress" style utilities rather than the newer GNU "gzip" based ones.

You need to use `gzcat` rather than `zcat`, assuming that it's available.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.

Also, I just learned that I was running the command on the school's Sun computers.  It's the linux pc's that my program needs to run on and they support zcat just fine.

Comment: Also works fine on mac with homebrew.

Answer (score 7):

I generally just use gzip directly when I want to gzip:

```
gzip -dc /file/address/file.tar.gz
```

Comment: ... or `gunzip -c /file/address/file.tar.gz`. This approach is portable between OS-X and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

gzip --decompress /file/address/file.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

```
zcat archive.tgz | tar -x --wildcards apri/fls/filename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ad the .Z to the end of the filename like this :

> zcat /file/address/file.tar.gz.Z

then it will find the file .